# How to contact EiC when his emails seems like auto computer generated reply

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

One of my article is under review in reputable IEEE journal. The average time of first decision for this journal is 3 months. However, my article is under review for 6.5 months and upon my inquiry I always get same email from EiC (editor-in-chief), which looks like an auto generated email, stating we appreciate your patience and we are trying to complete the process ASAP. According to journal policy, I cannot know who is the handling Associate Editor and all inquiries should go to EiC. 
In the given situation how can I invoke editorial board to expedite the process?
 Is it fine to make a call to EiC on his personal contact number?

Comment: Does the journal have a desk editor (that is, an employee of the publisher)? If so, you could try contacting him or her - the desk editor is likely to have more time, and could say something like "we've invited 3 reviewers of which 2 declined and the last review is due in ____ days".

Comment: on https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/ the only contact person is EiC, and on the Journal website under contact us the email of other two EiC is given.

Comment: What's the name of the journal? The link you gave doesn't work (it redirects to ScholarOne).

Comment: @Allure sorry for causing confusion "mc.manuscriptcentral.com" is the central system for submitting article for IEEE journals and other publishers. I am not sharing the name as I am afraid it may cause some problem for me, and for journal and EiC reputation.

Comment: What does EiC mean?

Comment: @henning: "Editor in Chief"

Comment: I guess, you can ask directly two EiCs with manuscript detail, something like “did you hear anything from reviewers yet?”

Answer (score 1):

I suggest contacting the publisher and asking them for a status update. The publisher is likely to have more time, and should be able to provide almost as good an update. [IEEE's website](https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/publications_contact.html) lists some people to contact. You might be able to find an even better contact person from the journal's website.

I'd write in the email:

1. Is my paper under review?
2. If it's under review, are there any problems (e.g. the only invited reviewers haven't responded to the invitation for 3 months, and no new ones have been invited)?
3. If there are problems, can you ask the EiC to look at the submission?

In a first email I wouldn't mention that I've already contacted the EiC. If they ask about that, then only I'd say I've contacted the EiC, but received what looks like an automated response.